# Gray square in Google Earth

Tags: google-earth

Near me there is an area on Google Earth that is covered up by a gray square:

[image]

The historical imagery for the tiles shows the underlying area and it is just a few ordinary upper middle class homes, nothing special or out of the ordinary.

Why would there be this random gray square appearing in just the current view?

Comment: FYI  Satellite map images with missing or unclear data https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_map_images_with_missing_or_unclear_data#United_States

Comment: I zoomed to the same coordinates and can see everything. Just a data transfer/rendering problem, I'm guessing.

Comment: Is it possible to clear the cache with Google Earth?  If so trying clearing it and zooming to the same area again.  I suspect it just hasn't downloaded correctly

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be some kind of cache corruption. So, the tiles are missing in the cache. They get rendered in historical mode, but not in current mode.

I restarted Google Earth and it did display the affected area, so it would appear to be just a cache corruption.